Running codellama in terminal using python without downloading the model
Is there any way to access the Codellama model without downloading the model itself? Like a simple Python program asking the user for the prompt and outputting the answer from the LLM using an API or something?

you can do it by using ollama. install ollama and follow the ollama github repo to do so. they have very well described it
